# Long time running PHP script on Apache with separate MySQL server restarting without manual refresh

Tags: mysql, php, apache-2.4

We're currently making a migration and experiencing a problem we're curious on solving correctly.

Our setup is a **separate web server running Apache 2.4 and a database server running MySQL 5.7**. We have a **PHP script which will take around one hour to complete**. The function of the script is to request information from the database server, parse it and then insert in new schemas on the server- while this happens nothing is sent to the client, this is only done when the script completes.

We've tried this on several development environments without problems but on the production setup (with two different physical servers) we ran into a problem.

**The script runs for a good while, around but not exactly 30 minutes and then it restarts without sending a response to the client.** Network log in a browser says there's one request but the apache access logs says there are one for each retry made.

The script is not made for being able to be run several times so since this happened we had to rollback and restart.

Our workaround is to split the migration in smaller batches, which works out fine, but we have an interest in understanding why this happens so we're reaching out here.

**Does anyone know what could be the culprit and how to solve it?**

We've found Apache settings like **`Timeout`**, **`KeepAliveTimeout`** and **`MaxKeepAliveRequests`** but we're not sure if that's the path to the solution and if changing this effects normal usage and perhaps some cron jobs running.

What can be the cause of the script restarting without giving the client response and what should be done to make sure the script doesn't restart itself.

**Thank you in advance** :)

/Thomas

Comment: Check your logs.

Comment: Thanks Michael, should've been clearer on that:
Client logs says request made, no responses, just waiting
Apache access logs creates new entries every time a new request is made (which happens after around 30 minutes).
Any log in particular you're referring to that might help?

Comment: How much RAM, which products are running, do you have any swap configured, etc?

Comment: Thanks Rick. Have been monitoring ram and cpu - apache incl. script uses about 1 GB out of 32 so no way near this.

Wondering about rephrasing the question: How can apache create several access.log entries when the browser only reports one request? What can be the cause of that and where to find the log for this?